# Bookmarklet to cause stack overflow to only show questions with "interesting tags"

Tags: discussion

**Very busy, yet still want to participate in the Stack Overflow community?**

Sometimes, I'd like to only see questions that contain one of my "interesting tags".  SO does not appear to have that feature (at this point).

**My answer:**

I placed the following in a bookmark on my browser:

```
javascript:$("div.question-summary").not('div.tagged-interesting').hide() && $('a.question-hyperlink').attr('target', '_blank');
```

It will hide all questions that are not highlighted, and cause the links on the remaining questions to open in a new browser window.

Comment: works wonderfully! thanks for making this!

Comment: If only jQuery could be used in all bookmarklets.

Comment: Or you could write a Greasemonkey script that greys out all other questions.

Comment: You can post your answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I haven't get it to work. How exactly is one supposed to execute the script to make it work?