# Is there a way to display only questions from my interesting tags?

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, tag-watching

Is there way for me to see all the latest questions from **all** my interesting tags on one site? If not, there should be a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Check this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25239/how-can-i-see-all-the-posts-matching-my-interested-tags/25245#25245):

> This is what I do
>
> > > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash+OR+flex+OR+actionscript+OR+actionscript-3
>
> Make a url matching your tags and bookmark it.

Answer (score 3):

Yep.  Behold! the glory of REST: you just construct a URL like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/[tag 1]+...+[tag n]
```

For example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interesting-tags+tags+support+feature-request This questions appears to have a unique tag set.

**EDIT**:
You can add the OR operator if you:

[https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interesting-tags tags OR support OR feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interesting-tags%20tags%20OR%20support%20OR%20feature-request)

And if you want to actually be able to *read* what you're typing you can use space rather than `+`...

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No, wait, that is not what I wanted. I need an OR-Operation. When I construct: stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/… I only get one result. But I want to see the latest questions in either "c", "matlab" or "python". Is this also possible?

Answer (score 2):

Shameful plug: [A Greasemonkey script to make browsing interesting tags easier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21717/a-greasemonkey-script-to-make-browsing-interesting-tags-easier)

In particular the "View All Interesting" feature.

Comment: Shameful, really. +1

Comment: @beggs: Edited.

Answer (score 2):

User [gahooa](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131040/gahooa) created [a bookmarket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14041/bookmarklet-to-show-the-whipp) to do this:

```
javascript:$("div.question-summary").not('div.tagged-interesting').hide()%20&&%20$('a.question-hyperlink').attr('target',%20'_blank');
```