# Show Questions from only selected programming language

Tags: support

is there any option to show question only from my favorite languages ?
when i click on QUESTIONS it shows my favorite tags questions in yellow !
but i want to see only questions from my selected languages every time !
is it possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to display only questions from my interesting tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32392/is-there-a-way-to-display-only-questions-from-my-interesting-tags)

Comment: +1 I was surprised at first that this was not the default behavior. Maybe this is what the "ignored tags" does? Even if so, it makes more sense to include a few tags than explicitly ignore many.

Comment: @YOU: Shouldn't there be an easier way? Those solutions are pretty raw.

Comment: @Madmartigan, there is! take a look at - http://stackexchange.com/tagsets/popular - you can create your own too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just bookmark tagged question page in your browser.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+OR+jquery+OR+javascript

or create customized tags at Stack Exchange Tag Sets.

https://stackexchange.com/tagsets/popular

You can import your current favorite tags to Tag Sets, and for more info about tag sets, you may need to take a look more meta question about that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-sets)

Comment: Tag Sets - I'm glad to know about that! Much more organized, PLUS you get feeds from all the sites. Perfect. I still have a lot to learn about these sites, thanks for sharing this.